# Markdown inside an if statement with Streamlit

Tags: if-statement, markdown, streamlit

I am trying to print a paragraph with `st.markdown` in Streamlit. It was working correctly before putting it inside the if statement but now I only get a code cell:

```py
if LOGGED_IN == True:
    st.markdown('''___\n
    bla bla bla
    ___''')
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the indentation before the markdown text. This works:

```py
if LOGGED_IN is True:
    st.markdown('''___\n
bla bla bla
___''')
```